# plotly line graph iterate over columns and loop trace

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Taking this post [Plot multiple columns on line graph using Dash/Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809312/plot-multiple-columns-on-line-graph-using-dash-plotly) as a reference, I'm looking to plot similar dataframe into line graph using plotly. What makes me stuck is how to put trace into a loop so that all item will be plot as difference trace data.

```
data = {'year':['2018','2019'],
    'jan':[20009,49599],
    'feb':[13000,22000],
    'mac':[23345,45888],
    'apr':[23399,23399]}

 df=pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('year')

        apr     feb     jan     mac
 year               
 2018   23399   13000   20009   23345
 2019   23399   22000   49599   45888
```

This is the closest code manage to get:

```
     month = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April']
     res=[]
     for item in df.index:
          res=go.Scatter(
              x=month,
              y=df.values.tolist(),
              mode='lines',
              name='df.index',
              )
     data=[res]
     layout = dict(title = 'Budget Monthly',
          xaxis= dict(title= 'month',ticklen= 5,zeroline= False)
         )
     fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
     py.iplot(fig, filename='line')
```

[Line plot but no separate trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOTof.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hope I got your idea correctly))

I had a similar issue some time ago and was very happy to find the cufflinks package.

To install cufflinks you need to execute the following commands:

```
pip install cufflinks
pip install ipywidgets
```

and restart your notebook if you are using Ipython.

And here is the code sample to build such plots:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

data = {'year':['2018','2019'],
    'jan':[20009,49599],
    'feb':[13000,22000],
    'mar':[23345,45888],
    'apr':[23399,23399]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('year')
df=df.transpose()


import cufflinks as cf

py.iplot([{
    'x': df.index,
    'y': df[col],
    'name': col
}  for col in df.columns], filename='cufflinks/multiple-lines-on-same-chart')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your help. It works. But only on jupyter notebook. When I put this config in django, import cufflinks give me  error 
     "ImportError: cannot import name 'FigureWidget'

Comment: ji.sein, the same error appeared to me in Jupyter as well, due to the config error inside the Plotly lib. In jupyter, it could be fixed by installing separately ipywidgets. Unfortunately, I do not know how are widgets implemented in django.